# require is not a function in angular 2 highchart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to create a highstock. But I am getting require is not a function in console. I have tried several ways. Able to remove error from file but still getting error in console.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock

Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please use `import` syntax, instead of `require` and import Highstock module before the `highchartsFactory()` function definition, then you will be able to return the imported module from your factory function. Please take a look at code below:

```
import stock from 'highcharts/highstock';
export function highchartsFactory() {
  return stock  
}
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-zjv1n3

Here is the answer for your question:
https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/require-is-not-a-function-in-angular2-highchart-t40602/